# Moving JavaScript output into other area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble moving my JavaScript output (`start`) from the black box into the grey box. I'm not entirely sure what to put into the functions (`moveRight` and `moveLeft`) to get the output to move from one to another.

I've tried searching up a solution but was not able to find one. I'm sure there is a nicer way to present this code but I'm still currently learning the basics. Thank you.

```js
function start() {
  var txt;
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = person;
  }
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = txt;
}

function moveRight(start) {

}

function moveLeft(start) {

}
```

```css
.blackbox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  background: #000000;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.greybox {
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  background: #323232;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.part3 {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="part3">
  <button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
  <button type="reset">Clear</button><br><br><br>

  <div class="part3">
    <div class="blackbox" id="text"></div>
    <div class="button">
      <br>
      <button type="button" onclick="moveRight(start)">--></button><br><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="moveLeft(start)"><--</button>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="greybox" id="name"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code makes the buttons swap the value between the black and gray boxes

```js
var txt;

function start() {
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (person == null || person == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = person;
    }
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = txt;
}

function moveRight() {
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = txt;
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = '';
}

function moveLeft() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = txt;
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = '';
}
```

```css
.blackbox{
    width:250px;
    height:125px;
    background:#000000;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
}

.greybox{
    width:250px;
    height:125px;
    background:#323232;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    height: 90px;
    line-height: 90px;
}

.button{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.part3{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="part3">
<button type="button" onclick="start()">Start</button>
<button type="reset">Clear</button><br><br><br>

<div class="part3">
<div class="blackbox" id="text"></div>
<div class="button">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="moveRight()" >--></button><br><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="moveLeft()" ><--</button>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="greybox" id="name"></div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```